# Spring boot - FirebaseMessaging Service injection is not working in another service

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I am trying to send firebase push notifications from a spring boot application.

Here I configured the `FirebaseMessaging` like:

```
@Configuration
class FirebaseConfig {

    var logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirebaseConfig::class.java)

    @Value("\${app.firebase-config-file}")
    lateinit var firebaseConfigPath: String

    @Bean("firebaseMessaging")
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun firebaseMessaging(): FirebaseMessaging {
        val firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions
            .builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(ClassPathResource(firebaseConfigPath).inputStream))
            .build()
        val app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions, "QInspect")
        logger.info("Firebase application has been initialized")
        return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(app)
    }
}
```

Here is the service I am using to send the push notifications:

```
@Service
class FirebaseNotificationService constructor(
    @Autowired val firebaseMessaging: FirebaseMessaging,
    @Autowired val mobileDeviceLogService: MobileDeviceLogService
) {

    private var logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirebaseNotificationService::class.java)
    private val gson = Gson()

    fun sendNotification(token: String, title: String, body: String): Status {
        try {
                val notification = Notification
                    .builder()
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setBody(body)
                    .build()
                val message = Message
                    .builder()
                    .setToken(token)
                    .setNotification(notification)
                    .build()
                firebaseMessaging.send(message)
                logger.info("Firebase Notification sent)
            return Status(Constants.ResponseCode.SUCCESS, "Success")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.error("Firebase Notification Failed: ${e.printStackTrace()}")
        }
        return Status(Constants.ResponseCode.EXCEPTION, "Failed")
    }
}
```

I can able to send the push notification using postman using the endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping("/notification")
@RestController
class NotificationResource constructor(@Autowired val firebaseService: FirebaseNotificationService) {

    @RequestMapping(value = ["/message"], method = [RequestMethod.POST])
    @ApiOperation(value = "Send firebase push notification with token", authorizations = [Authorization(value = "basic"), Authorization(value = "oauth2", scopes = [])])
    @ResponseBody
    @Throws(FirebaseMessagingException::class)
    fun sendNotificationMsg(@RequestParam(value = "title", required = true) title: String, @RequestParam(value = "body", required = true) body: String): Status {
        val user = SessionUtil.getUser()
        return firebaseService.sendNotification(user.token, title, body)
    }
```

**Now the problem is when I am trying to inject the `FirebaseNotificationService` in another service to send the push notifications, But it's not working without any errors.**

```
@Service
@Transactional
class MessageSubscriber {

@Autowired
var firebaseService: FirebaseNotificationService? = null

  fun sendPush() {
     firebaseService?.sendNotification("token", "Some Title", "Some body")
  }

}
```

What I am missing here?

**Update:**

I got the issue, it's my mistake it is going inside the `FirebaseNotificationService` but failing to get the user token which I didn't mention. It was returning here.

```
val notificationToken =
                tokenService.getTopByUserId(user.uuid!!)
                    ?: return Status(Constants.ResponseCode.FAILED, "User or token not found")
```

Comment: Please include the log when app started and when hitting `/message` POST api.

Comment: I got the issue, it's my mistake it is going inside the `FirebaseNotificationService` but failing to get the user token which I didn't mention. Just updated my question.